# PageNavigation Plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, system-plugin

I need to move the |Next/Prev* buttons, located in the **pagenavigation** plugin to after the `<jdoc:include type="component" />;` 
Basically render it anywhere in my templates' **index.php**?

Any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Edited**

Assuming you have created a template override of the article view, then you have to modify a few things at `templates\mytemplate\html\com_content\article\default.php`

Declare a global variable as below

```
global $myPageNavigation;
$myPageNavigation = $this->item->pagination;
```

Remove all the snippets that render the pagination which are associated to `paginationposition` and `paginationrelative`.

Then place the code below anywhere in your `template\mytemplate\index.php`

```
echo $GLOBALS['myPageNavigation'];
```

That is't, just a POC though.

> **Previous Answer**

Assuming your Joomla version is 2.5.x or 3.x, below is my pseudo concept using
[JPagination](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JPagination.html), [JInput](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JInput.html) and by creating a simple pagination module.

First, in your component's view, you need to remove the snippet that render the pagination and also set three JInput values which are required for your pagination module.

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$jinput->set( 'total', $total);
$jinput->set( 'limitstart', $limitstart);
$jinput->set( 'count', $count);
```

Then implement a module to render a pagination something like below,

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$total = $jinput->getInt( 'total', 0);
$limitstart = $jinput->getInt( 'limitstart', 0);
$count = $jinput->getInt( 'count', 10);
jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
$pageNav = new JPagination($total, $limitstart, $count);
```

and you can echo the pagination in your module's view something like

```
echo $pageNav->getResultsCounter(); 
echo $pageNav->getPagesLinks();
echo $pageNav->getPagesCounter();
```

Finally, assign your module to any position in your template which must also be associated with your component's menu.

Comment: Hey, that's awesome, but unfortunately I don't need the pagination. It's the page navigation [next and prev buttons for articles] that I need. I have assumed that this can't be done due to the way the 'page nav' is built from  a category.

Comment: My mistake, since your question isn't very clear. Answer has been updated. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ahhh, Clever! Nice little work around. Thanks!!